# JTextfield full width in gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, width, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

[image]

The layout of the JFrame in the picture is a GridBagLayout. The e-mail JTextfield has a gridwidth of 3. Is there any possibility to give this JTextfield a 100% width to fill the whole grid cell?

The fields are added dynamically. So give it a static width value width setColumns is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
button = new JButton("Button");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
yourPanel.add(button, c);
```